# Python setup.py: how to include local package dependency?

Tags: python, setup.py

The question is pretty much self explanatory. I have got a .zip package dependency that I need to include in my python package installation. So how do I include this local dependency in my `setup.py`? I have got `install_requires` but this loads my dependency packages from PyPI which is not what I want in this case.

The most relevant files in my project are structured as follows:

```
myproject
|- setup.py
|- mypackage
   |- __init__.py
   |- vendor
      |- __init__.py
      |- dependencies
         |- StreamingDataReader.zip
```

I then tried ...

```
include_package_data=True,
package_data={
    'StreamingDataReader': ['mypackage/vendor/dependencies/StreamingDataReader.zip'],
}
```

... with no success. My code can't still locate the package: `ImportError: No module named 'StreamingDataReader'`

Comment: There are a couple of ways to include data files.  Have you read the [Including Data Files](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files) section of the `setuptools` documentation?

Comment: I have been coming across this `package_data` but I have not found any complete example

Comment: Could you share the directory structure of your project, including where the relevant files are?

Comment: The `package_data` map is constructed as `{'Name of Pacakge': ['list', 'of', 'patterns']}`. Try something more like `{'': ['*.zip']}`.  That should include every `.zip` file in your project.

Comment: Thank you. But `['mypackage/vendor/dependencies/StreamingDataReader.zip']` is still a pattern

Comment: I think the problem there is that `StreamingataReader` is not one of the packages included in your project.

Comment: It is. I edited the post to include a basic project structure

Comment: A [package](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-regular-package) is a directory containing a file named `__init__.py`.

Comment: Yes I just did not have it in the post

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I have something to say about it, so I'm posting.

You have two separate problems here. The first is that the zip file needs to be included in your distribution. To do this, use `package_data` as you're intending, but you need to specify, for **your** package, what data within it you want to include. You do this as follows:

```
   package_data= {"mypackage": ["vendor/dependencies/StreamingDataReader.zip"]}
```

Do *not* use `include_package_data` at the same time; this looks for data in `MANIFEST.in` and ignores the `package_data` parameter. `setuptools` is really badly designed for managing this. The best advice I've found, for both binary and source packaging, is to ensure that all your data is within the package directory, and to use `package_data` and nothing else.

Your second problem is that you want to be able to import `StreamingDataReader`. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, there's no way to do this with `pip` using `pip install` and nothing else. You have two obvious choices:

(1) You can include a `requirements.txt` file and list the zip file as a requirement, and have people do `pip install -r requirements.txt` in advance of `pip install`ing your project. Your `requirements.txt` file would look like this:

```
./mypackage/vendor/dependencies/StreamingDataReader.zip
```

But requiring the user to do that may be an unacceptable level of pain, and it won't work for anyone who *depends* on your package.

(2) Brute force. Just use `zipfile` to expand the package.

I'm going to assume that `StreamingDataReader.zip` file is a Python package zip, with a single directory at the toplevel (I'm assuming it's called `StreamingDataReader`) which contains a toplevel `setup.py` and a subdirectory, let's assume it's called `StreamingDataReader`, which contains the actual software. In other words, I assume your zip looks like this:

```
StreamingDataReader/
StreamingDataReader/setup.py
StreamingDataReader/StreamingDataReader/__init__.py
```

etc. I'm also going to assume that you're running Python 3.3 or later, in which having an `__init__.py` file is no longer required to create a package hierarchy. (In previous versions, you'd need to manipulate `sys.path`, which isn't a big deal, but it's now easier.) So `vendor/__init__.py` isn't doing any work for you.

This solution, by the way, assumes that the folks who *run* your software will have write permission on the directory which contains it.

Put the following in your toplevel `__init__.py`:

```
import zipfile, pathlib

_mpath = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent
_sdrDir = mpath.joinpath("vendor", "dependencies", "StreamingDataReader")
if not _sdrDir.is_dir():
    _z = zipfile.Zipfile(sdrDir.parent.joinpath("StreamingDataReader.zip"), "r")
    _z.extractall(sdrDir.parent)
    _z.close()
    del _z
# cleanup
del _mpath
del _sdrDir
```

Once you do this, you can

```
import mypackage.vendor.dependencies.StreamingDataReader.StreamingDataReader as StreamingDataReader
```

wherever you want.

Then, finally, in the `setup.py` for your package, you'll need to include the *dependencies* for `StreamingDataReader`, because you're not recursively installing it with `pip`.

Yes, that's a lot of work. But as far as I know, there's no facility in the Python installation mechanism for otherwise installing a package from a zip file you provide yourself.